# What is an appropriate way to write a memory profiling wrapper around new/delete?

Tags: c++, malloc, wrapper, new-operator, free

I wish to understand how to write a good wrapper for memory profiling of the calls I've made.
In C, my wrapper looked something like this.
For calloc, `void* wrapperCalloc(size_t nitems, size_t size)`. This would internally use some structs to keep track of how many bytes of memory had been allotted as well as number of calls made to calloc, create the void pointer and return it.
For free, it would be like `void wrapperFree(void* ptr, size_t size)` and in size I would pass in `sizeof(*T)` where T was the type of `ptr`.

My issue now in C++ is that I do not know what the return type of my new wrapper will be since we use `new` in C++ which internally determines the type and returning a typed pointer accordingly.

Comment: See if this helps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/238533/183642

Comment: Thank you so much, this is helpful. I am not totally aware of templates but I will spend time understanding it as it seems to serve my purpose.

Comment: As for most subject, there are several ways to do that in C++, and it also depends at which level you want to check that (defining specific **allocator** for some container class, overloading new/delete at class scope or at global scope).

Comment: The example in my link keeps track of allocations/deallocations to detect memory leaks and double-frees. You may use it as an example of a custom wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has the concept of an ["allocator"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Allocators). This is a specific class meant to abstract away details of memory management. All STL containers have this as a template argument. They get passed an allocator, and they use it as a source of memory. If this fits your design, use it and make custom allocators.

---

A [lower-level way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new) to take control of memory management is to overload operator new/delete. These operators can be overloaded for individual classes, or for the whole system:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>

void*
operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
  if (!sz) sz = 1; // can't allocate 0 bytes
  if (void* p = std::malloc(sz)) return p;
  throw std::bad_alloc{};
}

void*
operator new[](std::size_t sz)
{
  if (!sz) sz = 1; // can't allocate 0 bytes
  if (void* p = std::malloc(sz)) return p;
  throw std::bad_alloc{};
}

void
operator delete(void* const ptr) noexcept
{
  std::free(ptr);
}

void
operator delete[](void* const ptr) noexcept
{
  std::free(ptr);
}
```

These are used internally when you do something like `new T[100]`. One thing to look out for is that the data structures you use in these functions should not themselves call new/delete, or else that would cause an infinite recursion. So, make some kind of a malloc-allocator for STL containers if you need them in implementations of these functions.

---

You can also see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U) cppcon talk for more on allocators in general.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I haven't used operator overloading but I will look into it. But what about the constructor call when I say for example new MyClass(); ?
Are you suggesting that the constructor call is a separate step that is inserted by compiler on its own?

Comment: @SankalpSangle Yes, calling constructors/destructors is handled separately by the compiler. These operators are only concerned with memory allocation/deallocation. You simply define these in the global scope and be super careful to not cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you. And finally, can new operator be overloaded in specific scopes so that I can implement my memory profiling only for certain classes/scopes that I want to keep track of?

Comment: @SankalpSangle yes, absolutely. You can overload the class-level operator new/delete which will only handle that class. STL containers also have concept of an "allocator" which can also be useful. Look them up.